# How to find the source for an artifact version in Maven?

Tags: maven, dependency-management

Assuming I have Maven pom (let's say Maven 3.8) like this:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

   <parent>
      <groupId>some.group</groupId>
      <artifactId>my-parent</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0</version>
   </parent>

   <artifactId>my-app</artifactId>
   <packaging>jar</packaging>

   <dependencies>

      <dependency>
         <groupId>some.group</groupId>
         <artifactId>my-artifact</artifactId>
      </dependency>
   </dependencies>
</project>
```

...where `my-parent` has a dependency management section, maybe bom imports and further parents up the chain with it's own dependency management sections, how can I find the source of the version of `some.group:my-artifact` that actually used in the child pom?

Let's say, I build this and see that the effective pom contains version `1.2.3` for this artifact, how can I find out the pom that actually contains that version?

Comment: If you are in an ide with maven support, you should find it while clicking at the dependency

Comment: @Jens I have IntelliJ and even the maven helper that provides the dependency analyzer. When clicking on the dependency, I does not take me to the definition of the version, it takes me to the pom of the effective version.

Comment: I have the same question. I found an artifact in mvnrepository.com, now I want to locate the git repo where the source code of the artifact is stored, How do I go about locating this?